# Does calling CloseHandle on a file handle open for writing imply FlushFileBuffers too?

Tags: c, winapi, handle, io-buffering

I encountered code similar to this (stripped down for MCVE):

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(argv[1], GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 
// Note: FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH are not present
DWORD dwWritten;

WCHAR wBOM = 0xFEFF, wString[100] = L"Hello World!";

SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hFile, &wBOM, sizeof(WCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, wString, wcslen(wString) * sizeof(WCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);

FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

The last part struck me as pedantic since I had the impression that calling `CloseHandle` would flush any buffered output to disk (similar to `fclose(FILE *)`, where it is [explicitly documented](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.1p2) by the C Standard that buffers will be flushed). However, I wasn't able to find this information in the documentation for [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) on MSDN.

So, is the call to `FlushFileBuffers` immediately before closing the file handle necessary to avoid discarding buffered output?

Comment: call `FlushFileBuffers` of course not necessary. any your data write will be not discarded (only if system not crash just after)

Comment: See [File Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-caching) on MSDN for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing the handle does not discard unflushed updates, but it does not flush them either.

[`FlushFileBuffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers)() is useful if you want to force flushing before [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle)() because the latter does not flush the buffers automatically. However, if you really need direct writes, you must open the handle with [`FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea).

If you do not read direct writes, then flushing is not necessary either before closing the handle or at any point of the life of the handle.